# javascript oop namespaces and inheritance

Tags: javascript

It create in name spaces object and I can use it.

```
Test = {};
Test.Car = function init(color){
    this.color = color;
}  
Test.Car.prototype.paint = function(color) {
    return this.color = color;
};
Test.Car.prototype.print = function(){
    return this.color;
}
```

Example of use:

```
var Car4 = new Test.Car('Blue');
Car4.paint('red');
alert(Car4.print());
```

Now I want to create new object and I want to inheritance form test:

Test2 = {}
to do here to inheritance  form Test and override using prototype ?
Test2.prototype = Object.create(Test.prototype); not working

How can I do it. Need some help in that.

Comment: Test is the namespace and car is your object. did you meant you wanted to inherit from the Car object

Comment: `Test` isn't a namespace, it's just an object. `Object.create(Test.prototype)` doesn't work because `Test` isn't a function. What is it you want to "inherit" from `Test`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: correct, I meant the OP is trying to assume the Test object as his namespace or in other words the container

Comment: @unikorn: Actually I was talking to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

`Test` is an object, not a "namespace" or a function, although sometimes people call objects that you put properties on namespaces (they aren't, really).

I'm not sure why you'd want to, but you can use `Test` as the prototype of `Test2` by doing this:

```
var Test2 = Object.create(Test);
```

Now things like this work:

```
var c = new Test2.Car();
```

...because `Test2` inherits `Car` from `Test`.

If you wanted to create a **`Car2`**, that's slightly more involved:

```
var Car2 = function() { // Or `Test.Car2 = function` or whatever
    Test.Car.apply(this, arguments);
    // Or: `Test.Car.call(this, "specific", "arguments", "here");`

    // ...Car2 stuff...
};
Car2.prototype = Object.create(Test.Car.prototype);
Car2.prototype.constructor = Car2;
```

Comment: That was key var Test2 = Object.create(Test);